# Linux File Permissions for Wireshark USB Monitoring via setfacl

Tags: linux, usb, file-permissions, zsh

According to the [Wireshark Docu](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) for usb monitoring,
one might want to allow a non-sudo user to read the usbmon devices.

`sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:r /dev/usbmon*`

This command returns the error `setfacl: Option -m incomplete` though.
The manpage for `setfacl` did not help.
**How does one allow the current user to read the usbmon devices via setfacl?**

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the `:r` solved the problem:
`sudo setfacl -m u:$USER\:r /dev/usbmon*`

Maybe this is caused by interpretation within the zsh shell?